# Javascript/aspx call server side function with parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

This is my JavaScript code and I want to send parameter to the function instead of `"7789"` to send the `var: nalogID`  I have tried only with `__doPostBack('updatePrikaceniDoc', nalogID);` but it does not work so I don't know what to do now.

```
   function update(nalogID) 
                <%updatePrikaceniDoc("7789")%>
                __doPostBack('updatePrikaceniDoc', nalogID);
            }
```